# Query all documents contains a list with multiple elements with the same value

Tags: mongodb, list, mongodb-query, element, multiple-instances

I tried to find a solution to this specific issue:
I want to get all the documents that in their list ('metadata') there are more then one element with the same category.

An example:

[image]

As to the example above:

I have a document with 'metadata' list and there are more than one element with the same category ('yaw_rate') so I want to receive this document.

If I had just one element (or no elements) that matches that category I don't want to get this document.

Answer (score 1):

this is possible through [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/):

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$metadata'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: '$_id',
        category: '$metadata.category'
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'your_collection_name',
      localField: '_id._id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'object'
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$object._id',0]
      },
      metadata: {
        $arrayElemAt: ['$object.metadata',0]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the last two stages are looking up resulted `id`s from previous stages, with your original collection, and obtaining wanted information from documents. if you just need the `id`s, these stages are unnecessary.